# Angular2 click a dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using a 3rd party module (a datepicker) which resolves itself as the below in the DOM (my written html only has the datepicker element)

```
<material-datepicker>
  <div>
    <input>
```

I want to be able to programmatically execute a click on that input. I've tried attaching a local var to the datepicker element but of course that item isn't listening for a click. I dug in and ended up with the below which I really thought should work, but isn't...

```
 const ref = this.datepicker.elementRef;
 const input = ref.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
 console.log('INPUT', input)
 input.click();
```

The output of input above is a legitmate looking input element

```
<input _ngcontent-c2="" class="datepicker__input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" readonly="true" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="2017/06/11" placeholder="Select a date" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);">
```

However the click doesn't do anything. I looked into the module itself and it doesn't do anything fancy on the click event so it should work.

I can't provide a jsfiddle or anything because it relies on this 3rd party module, https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? If you are tying a click event to the input, can we see that piece of code? Or are you just trying to get focus on the input?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when `input.click()` is executed? Do you have a handler attached that is listening for the click event?

Comment: Why not [**Material2#datepicker**](https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker)? :)

Comment: Yes the module I'm using (Angular-2-Datepicker) has a click event on that Input.  Taken from their component it looks like `<input (click)="onInputClick()">` and that function handles the opening

Comment: @developer033 yes good call I think that'll work out thanks... however; for curiosity's sake I'd still like to know how to access the dynamically generated input mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `picker.onInputClick()` method:

**template.html**

```
<material-datepicker #picker [(date)]="yourModelDate"></material-datepicker>
<button (click)="picker.onInputClick(); $event.stopPropagation()">Open manually</button>
```

Note `$event.stopPropagation()` is required here because datepicker handles document click

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/yOATBEaHhZfEL1PSq3nk?p=preview)**

Comment: Awesome thanks yurzui, it was the topPropagation I was missing!